# How can I prevent methods from being added to a class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to stop functions/methods from being added (**EDIT: by other developers**) to a class for the case where the object is a Model or DTO which should not contain methods (to prevent 'abuse' of the Models/DTOs by others, who may try and add 'helper' methods etc).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Write a custom CodeAnalysis (FxCop) or "Roslyn" rule, add that to your build process producing an error if violated.

Comment: @NickG the question is too broad and a bit confusing - what do structs have to do with preventing methods? Do you or don't you want to inherit from the class?

Comment: @NickG I mean, it sounds glib, but there's only so much the type system can do for you. Lets say I wanted to ensure the other developers on my team don't name all their variables after famous monty python sketches. There's no way to get the compiler to enforce that, short of adding a comment saying `/* Hey you, stop doing that */` and boxing the ears of whoever is doing it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually I didn't realise structs can have methods in  C#!

Comment: @NickG This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - having a problem but asking about the attempted solution, not the actual problem. What actual problem are you trying to solve? Making it *easier* to create DTOs for example makes it *less* likely that people will try to create one big DTO blob - they don't have to! Putting the DTOs in a *separate* DLL is another option, which can help with communication between layers or projects

Comment: You can also use a mapping library like AutoMapper to map from one DTO to another using conventions in a *very* easy way, making people *prefer* to create their own DTOs and methods rather than try to mess with the One Big DTO

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah but I guess it's probably easier to just inherit directly from the DTO so no mapping is needed. I'm not sure if that's bad-practice or not.

Comment: @Moderator, why remove C# from the question title? The question is C# specific and answers will be different for any other language.  Now if you search for this question, it's totally unclear in the search results which language this question is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use reflection and write a unit test that fails if a model-class has methods.

Mark all you model classes with a custom attribute. Then make a unit test that uses reflection to load a given assembly, iterate all classes in that assembly and check that classes marked with the model attribute does not have methods.  This should be fairly straight forward using reflection.

Comment: Don't forget to construct an inheritance graph and examine all derived types to ensure they don't have methods. If you can't trust someone not to add methods, you certainly can't trust them to add your attribute.

Comment: @Asad don't worry - I was mainly asking out of curiosity rather than anything else :)   We don't have a big problem with this and I may not even implement the proposed solutions. I just wondered if there was a "quick fix"

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are trying to solve a procedural issue with code where you should be using communication.

Your colleagues (i assume) are operating on the code files with 'full trust' privileges. If they break that privilege you should open a dialogue. Use the change as an opportunity to educate them on the intended design. Perhaps they are correct and you will be educated!

I suggest simply making the intended design obvious in the class name and with a comment stating the intended nature. Perhaps quote the design document(s) that informed the class.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot **hinder** anyone with full write-access to your code-base to do so. The only two things you may do to **avoid** it are create some CodeAnalysis-rule for FXCop as mentioned by *Christian.K* in the comments or by writing your DTO-class so that it is undoubtly a DTO that should not have any methods by using a unambigious name for the class and if this is not enough provide some code-comments that notifies the coder to do not so.

However you may need some kind of method if using collections e.g. where you will need some kind of comparision if two instances of your DTO are equal, so you have to provide at least an `Equals`- and `GetHashCode`-method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a struct to prevent additions to a class. You can use the `sealed` keyword

```
public sealed class MyDTOObject { ... }
```

Now, you can not inherent a class and also prevent inheritance (which is essentially what you're asking). The very fact of inheriting `MyDTOObject` is creating a new class which is **based off of** not equal to, or restricted, or defined in any way by the implementation of `MyDTOObject`.

You can use an `abstract` class, to force derived classes to implement certain methods, but not the other way around.

If you want to prevent others from deriving from your class and implementing helper methods, you must use the `sealed` keyword, or mark the class internal.

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to prevent _any_ methods, that is even in "MyDTOObject" itself.

Comment: I think the OP has the requirement of wanting to be able to inherit and add properties, just not methods.

Comment: @Christian.K: and i'm saying that is impossible, other than making the class sealed to prevent inheritance. (he specified additions "by other developers")

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent inheritance (or anything similar). I think you've misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may prevent the class being extended or inherited by marking it **final** that way nobody would be able to extend your class and hence not being able to add any behavior.  But stop and ask yourself whether you want to do that or not,  because then you'd be signing an invisible contract that everything ever required by the class is written in the class and this class needs no further addition.

To be clear,  I was talking in Java context.